# Meteor create new template dynamicaly

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Is it possible to create a new template (from var or collection) when app is running ?

*something like this :*

`MyHtmlTmpl from var or collection > Create new Template.MyNewTmpl > Insert in dom`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit you'll need to

```
meteor add spacebars-compiler
```

Then you can write something like this:

```
function renderTemplateWithData (content, data, parent) {
  var newView = Blaze.With(
    data,
    eval(SpacebarsCompiler.compile(content, { isBody: true }))
  )
  Blaze.render(newView, parent)
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
renderTemplateWithData('<h1>{{title}}</h1>', { title : "hello world" }, document.body)
```

Comment: My var ( here MyHtmlTmpl ) isn't a Blaze Template. It's still the html with braced tags.

```var MyHtmlTmpl = "<h1>{{ title }}</h1>";```

Is there function to compile this in Blaze template  and after use your solution ( Blaze.renderWithData )

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but: `Blaze.renderWithData` can take a string as an argument. So you can do `Blaze.renderWithData('<h1>{{ title }}</h1>')`

Comment: I try this : 

`var MyHtmlTmpl = "<h1>{{ title }}</h1>";
    Blaze.renderWithData(MyHtmlTmpl, { title : "hello world" }, document.body);
// return <h1>{{ title }}</h1>`

and this (with <template name="foo">…</template>)

`Blaze.renderWithData(Template.foo, { title : "hello world" }, document.body);
// return <h1>hello world</h1>`

Comment: The return-value of `Blaze.renderWithData` is irrelevant. It appends the rendered HTML to `document.body`. Did it append `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>` ?

Comment: Exactly !

When meteor is running, each <template> has parsed and compiled in a template.js (.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/***.js).

And I not found function to make this…

Comment: My answer was complete bull. Sorry about that, I updated my answer.